# how to make pyomo lib portable？

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to know how to make use of pyomo in my program which call the python interpreter to exe some pyomo scripts, but it shows that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\site-packages\pyomo\environ\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    _import_packages()
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\site-packages\pyomo\environ\__init__.py", line 73, in _import_packages
    pkg.load()
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\plugins\__init__.py", line 12, in load
    import pyomo.opt.plugins.driver
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\plugins\driver.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pyomo.scripting.pyomo_parser
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\pyomo_parser.py", line 84, in <module>
    description=doc, epilog=epilog, formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter )
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\face\face\Release\lib\argparse.py", line 1647, in __init__
    prog = _os.path.basename(_sys.argv[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstaller` doesn't support secondary imports. You have to specify `hidden imports` of `pyomo` components in your `.spec` file